# Count Records and send email in Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

How do i achieve the below scenario in informatica.

We have to count the number of “No Match Records” and keep them for a later use. If I run the No Match Report today and I have 6 entries, I have to send an email to the business owner with a subject “count of records changed”.  Next run will be in a week time. Then when I count the number of no match records I may have the following
1)      I have 6 entries again
2)      I have different number of entries

If I have same number of entries as per previous run We have to send a report with subject “Count No Change”. If I have different number of entries from my previous run – then I have to send a different email.

Note : Both the source and target are in flatfiles.

Comment: Please be specific where you are facing problem.

Comment: thanks but could you please elaborately explain about the mapping flow design with transformation names and logic need to implement

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, I hope this will be useful for you

Mapping Level:

Lookup the Target data using Lookup transformation and compare with source data. If the data are different then load it into target file (Use filter transformation to filter the data)

Session Level:

```
Start->Session---TgtSuccessRows > 0 --> EmailTask1 (Counts not match)
          |------TgtSuccessRows = 0 ---> EmailTask2 (Counts match)
```

Create two email task, one for `Counts not match` and another for `Counts Match`. Based on the above link task  condition email will be Sent.

If the Source has same records in the second run, no data will be loaded. So TgtSuccessRows  will be `0` and `Counts match` email will be sent